# Magento 2: How to get quote product id in an observer?

Tags: magento, magento2, observers

Product id is not displaying and through this error **{"0": "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ** please help me to come out of this.

Here I want to return if the attribute code is not equal to 5431.

So how it is possible.

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
        
        //$quote = $block->getQuoteData();
        /* $quote= $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $item = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($item  as $_item){
        echo $_item->getProduct()->getId(); */
        
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        //$item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        foreach($event->getQuoteItem()  as $_item){
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
                
        $is_priscription = $product->getData('prescription');
        if($is_priscription != '5431'){
                return;
            }
        }
        
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks in Advance!

**Next Step**

This is my updated code I get Product id here, Now I want if product attribute option id is not equal to 5431 then redirect to success page i.e (order-success) and if oroduct option id is equal to 5431 then redirect to the url defined below (prescription/index)

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_order = $order;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
                    
        $orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        
        foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $_item){        
        $product = $_item->getProductId();  
        
        //echo $_item->getName(); die();
        
        $is_priscription =  $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription'); 
        
        
        if($is_priscription != '5431'){
        
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setPath('order-success');
            return $resultRedirect;
            }
        }
        
        $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the observer event name

Comment: observer name : softadroit_order_success & event name: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease try this below:

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderIds[0]);

        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        
        $item = $quote->getAllItems();

        foreach($item  as $_item){
        $product = $_item->getProduct();
                
        $is_priscription = $product->getData('prescription');
        if($is_priscription != "" && $is_priscription == '5431'){
                return;
            }
        }
        
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); 
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

After that please run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Comment: {"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Softadroit\\Prescription\\Observer\\Orderplaceafter","1" Thorugh this error

Comment: please run php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Again both are redirecting to same page

Comment: ```$is_priscription =  $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription');```

This is not getting any value in echo, I think here is the problem, can you please check it

Comment: You can get this data by this way
 $is_priscription = $_item->getProduct()->getData('prescription'); OR
 $is_priscription = $_item->getProduct()->getPrescription();

Answer (score 2):

If you are observing the event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` you don't have direct access to the quote. Only to the order. And you cannot get it from the Checkout session instance either because the quote is removed from the session before the event is dispatched.
But you can get the quote through the order.

you will need firts to add the quote repository as a dependency to your observer

```
private $quoteRepository;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    ....
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    ....
}
```

Then, in the `execute` method you can do this

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
$quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
$quote = $this->qupteRepository->get($quoteId);
if ($quote && $quote->getId()) {
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    //loop through items ....
}
```

This will get you what you are trying to do.
But I think a better idea would be to not use the quote and the products to get what you need.
You should save the product attribute value on the quote when it is added to the cart and then transfet this to the order item created from the quote item.
This way, in your observer you can do `$order = $observer->getOrder()` and then loop through the order items `$order->getAllItems()` and check what you need.

Comment: if ($quote && $quote->getId()) {
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    //loop through items ....
}  

 here if I have to update the item name then what should I have to do. please help.